# Reading array and matching IDs and updating value

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am going to be as descriptive as possible with this and see if anyone is able to assist me in a small script that I am writing.

I have the following `read_csv()` function which outputs the following items:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhwM5.png)

```
function read_csv()
{
    $options = [];
    $csv = WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . ('/files/Office.csv');
    $handle = fopen($csv, 'r');
    $include_headers = false;

    if (empty($handle) === false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
            if (!$include_headers) {
                $include_headers[] = $data;
            } else {
                $options[] = $data;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Now I have this function below and this is what I'm wanting to achieve:

- Read the `read_csv()` function and get the IDs
- Match the IDs to the `get_post_meta($place->ID, '_id', true)`.
- If the two IDs match, update_post_meta on `'map_url'` post_meta.

All help will be appreciated!

`var_dump($place_id)` & `var_dump($map_url)` output the following - I need to match the `$place_id` to the `$place_rows[0]` and then `update_post_meta` on that post w/ `$office_rows[2]`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kjdq.png)

```
function match_ids()
{
    $places = get_posts([
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_type' => 'places',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ]);

    if ($places) {
        $place_ids = [];
        $place_rows = read_csv();
        var_dump($place_rows);

        foreach ($places as $key => $place) {
            $place_id = get_post_meta($place->ID, '_id', true);
            var_dump($place_id);

            $map_url = get_post_meta($place->ID, 'map_url', true);
            var_dump($map_url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the below `for` loop should work as a replacement to what you have. I've included inline comments which hopefully make sense. I would recommend using the `var_dump` stuff as you were before, before actually using `update_post_meta` just in case I have a typo.

```php
foreach ($places as $key => $place) {

    $place_id = get_post_meta($place->ID, '_id', true);

    // Find _all_ that match, which is hopefully either one or zero items
    $place_row = array_filter(
        $place_rows,
        function($row) {
            // Whenever I work with CSV files I like to use ?? just in case
            // You could also just use == for a weaker comparison
            return (int)$place_id === (int)($row[0] ?? null);
        }
    );

    if(1 !== count($place_row)){
        // Not sure what to do if something isn't found, or if too many?
        continue;
    }

    // Grap the single array item
    $place_row = reset($place_row);

    // Whenever I work with CSV files I like to use ?? just in case
    $map_url = $place_row[2] ?? null;

    // Sanity check, just in case someone uploads a file with different columns
    if (false === filter_var($map_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // Not a value URL
        continue;
    }

    update_post_meta($place->ID, 'map_url', $map_url);

}
```